# How can I save Chrome bookmarks to prevent daily accidental deletion?

Tags: bookmarks

I accidentally deleted my folder of bookmarks that were exported from Internet Explorer to Google Chrome.

How can i save chrome bookmarks to prevent daily accidental deletion, so that this does not happen again?

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin/service called [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/) that saves your bookmarks remotely and can allow you to recover them later.

As for already deleted bookmarks, you might find them in your recycle bin. Otherwise, no, they're lost forever.